# how to load jinja2 templates from zipped folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I am trying to load templates from zipped folder but it won't. The folder structure is 
zipped.zip:
   templates/template1.html

I tried opening the file using zipfile module and passing the opened file handle to the get_template function as below

```
import os
from pathlib import path
import jinja2

TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.abspath(str(Path.home()))
TEMPLATE_LOADER = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath=TEMPLATE_DIR)
TEMPLATE_ENV = jinja2.Environment(loader=TEMPLATE_LOADER)

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('zipped.zip', 'r')
hd_template = archive.open('templates/parsing_error_template.html')
parsed_template = TEMPLATE_ENV.get_template(hd_template)
html_template = parsed_template.render(a='something')
```

The error I got:

```
parsed_template = TEMPLATE_ENV.get_template(parsed_template)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 168, in get_source
    pieces = split_template_path(template)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 27, in split_template_path
    for piece in template.split('/'):
AttributeError: 'ZipExtFile' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How do I load a jinja2 template from zipped folder?